# How to pass a jquery variable as an argument in C# function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

in the below code I am trying to pass a the cell value of jqgrid as a parameter in c# function but it is showing an error...

[image]

Comment: can you update code from variable declaration of `cellvalue`

Comment: `@CustomUrlHelper()` is razor code and is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. Your javascript variable does not exist at that point. You have not indicated what that function does, but one option is to use a 'dummy` value in place of `cellvalue` to generate its output, and then use javascript to replace the dummy value with the value of the variable.

Comment: that function encrypts the value of querystring variable and generates encrypted digest.  Stephen Muecke.

Comment: Please don´t post images of code, write the code itself instead. This makes it 1. easier to read, and 2. easier to be searched on the internet.

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding what custom formatter (the `formatter` callback function) do. Why `id` should be encrypted? If you really need to encrypt it then you should do this **on the server side** and the `id` value, will be already encrypted. You should examine your code, which generate the server response with the data of jqGrid. You can include encryption on the place if the encryption is really required.

Comment: ok @Oleg i think its a good idea to encrypt the id at server side code

Comment: @MohanSingh: Please include more detailed information about what you do: JavaScript code for example. The `datatype` is important. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Do you use `url` or `data` option to fill jqGrid with data? Probably you don't need any custom formatter at all.

Comment: @Oleg in the above code snippet i am showing all the details of students in jqgrid with a hyperlink(edit) in the last column of every row. and on click of that hyperlink i am passing the student id as query string and i want that querystring to be encrypted. the datatype is json and the jqgrid version is 4.4.

Comment: @MohanSingh: `CustomUrlHelper` will be executed *on the server side* and all parameters, which will be used have to be already known to be able to generate the HTML code. On the other part `formatter` is the callback function, which works *on the client side*. It's JavaScript function, which will be called in the loop. The parameters of the callback function will be known only after the `url` parameter of jqGrid will be called and return the data. The `formatter` will be called for every row of the data. Thus the whole current code, which you posted, has really no sense in the form.

Comment: @MohanSingh: You should look at the whole server and client code, which you wrote currently and move some parts on the correct place. It's important to divide the code on the part which runs on the client side (JavaScript code) and the server part (C# code) and to use clear interface between (like the controller action, which will be called via `url` parameter). The response of `url` should contains all what you need on the client side. You can include any custom additional information in the response of `url`. Moreover I recommend you don't use retro versions like 4.4 published 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not as simple as passing a JQuery value as a parameter to a C# function.

Rationale:

1. JQuery runs on the client machine
2. C# runs on your web server (as you
   are using ASP.NET here)

In order to pass parameters to your server, you need to implement some API calls using either REST or SOAP messaging.

You can also look into the runat='server' tag for older ASP.NET (non-MVC) projects if you are not going to be using MVC/WebAPI/WCF.

Comment: ok its fine. i am using this to encrypt Querystring so is there any other ways to secure querystring.

Comment: What is the purpose of encrypting your query string? If you don't want MITM attacks, that is a job for SSL/TLS. If you don't want your end-user to see your query string, you could use jquery.ajax methods to call your server methods.

Answer (score 0):

we can't directly pass the jquery variable in server side c# function , but we can do it using an alternative method ,that is by calling another jquery method and the second method calls server side method using jquery ,ajax call and the ajax method return the desired output string after success.

```
{
     name: 'Id', index: 'Id',
     formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
         var URLdata = "";
         debugger;
         BindTemperProofURL('@Url.Action("AddEventAttendee", "CampaignSchedule")', '', "Id=" + rowObject["Id"], function (data) { URLdata = data; })
         return '<a href="' + URLdata + '" style="width:75px; "class="jqgridlink">' + rowObject["Id"] + '</a>';

     }
},
```

```
function BindTemperProofURL(url, nonTamperProofParams, tamperProofParams, callback) {
    var SecureURL = "";
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("SecureURL", "Base", new { area = string.Empty }, null)', // we are calling json method
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { url: url, nonTamperProofParams: nonTamperProofParams, tamperProofParams: tamperProofParams },
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
    },
    async: false,
    error: function (ex) {
    }
});
```